# Dimming led ceiling fan with remote and dual switch wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, ceiling-fan, dimmer-switch

I currently have a similar setup for my Stile Anderson 22 in. LED Indoor/Outdoor Brushed Nickel Ceiling Fan with Remote Control.

[image]

Black wire controls the fan, while the blue controls the light kit on the fan. The only modification I made was to piggyback the light control from the remote to the blue/red wire nut. This way the remote module will control the fan and light (when the corresponding wall switch is in the ON position), and the other switch will control the light independently.

The problem I'm having is flickering of the led lights when using the remote dimmer control. Could this be a result of the modified wiring I've used or should I assume the issue is elsewhere. If it is a potential problem with my wiring is there and fix to keep the current operation the same? Thanks.

Comment: The drawing shows the black wire going through the receiver. Just to clarify, you've got the blue wire going through there? Are you sure that the receiver is designed for dimming the lights, not varying the speed of the fan? Do you have 2 receivers? A picture of the wiring in the box will help immensely, please [edit] your post to include it. Oh, and welcome to [diy.se]! After you've added the pic and are awaiting some answers, take the [tour] and browse through the [help] to learn how you can get the most out of the site.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please? Also, is using a different remote an option for you?